# Image not showing after Base 64 Conversion

Tags: flutter, dart

I am few months into Flutter, Ran into this issue where I have gotten a base64 String from an API, I have decoded the base 64 string and converted it to bytes. When I try to display it on an image widget I get nothing. Below is my code. and a snippet from my console. Thank you.

```
if (imgString != null) {
  _bytesImage = base64.decode(imgString.toString());
  print(_bytesImage);
  return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      child: Image.memory(
        _bytesImage,
        width: 300,
        height: 250,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ));
} else {
  print("Image String is null");
  return SizedBox.shrink();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please print json responce

Comment: added. Please have a look @ShubhamNarkhede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I just did this.

Added this under Build Widget.

I stored the base64 string in var called _imgString. It was containing some new line characters in it. So I used split function and joined them to get a proper format.

```
Uint8List _image = base64.decode(_imgString.split('\n').join());
    image = Image.memory(
      _image,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    );
```

You can call this image object in your widget tree wherever you want.

For eg.

```
Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                  height: 250.0,
                  width: 400,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    // for Vertical scrolling
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    child: image,
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: This saved me. Apparently when the image is big, Image.memory(base64.decode(stringImg)) will not work. Resolving the Uint8List beforehand was what was needed. Thanks!

Comment: @oupoup,  I got the same issue on my image ,I have use Image.memory do have alternative to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a Uint8List to a Flutter Image..

```
if (imgString != null) {
  _bytesImage = BASE64.encode(imgString.toString());
    Uint8List bytes = BASE64.decode(_bytesImage);
    print(bytes);
    return ClipRRect(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
       child: Image.memory(
             bytes,
             width: 300,
             height: 250,
             fit: BoxFit.cover,
             ));
       } else {
     print("Image String is null");
     return SizedBox.shrink();
  }
```

Comment: Please what library is the class BASE64 from?

Comment: Please whats the data type of your `_bytesImage`